# Getting rid of "translate" button next to search results

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

[This is the text i mean:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/015WN.jpg)

Next to some of my links, that lead to websites in languages other than the one my browser is set to, is displayed text that will transtlate the website. ("Přeložit" = "Translate")

However, it clashes with the "Search filter" extension that I have installed for getting rid of sites like Quora and Pinterest plaguing my internet search.

Is there some way of getting rid of this text?

I tried disabling it in the setting somehow, but I couln't find any solution there. There is a window of languages, that won't be translated, but I don't see any option for adding a language.